# How do I make pynput ignore letter keys when they are in a combination?

Tags: python, pyautogui, pynput

I am trying to make a program for Discord, where you can write with reactions, and it works like this:

when the key is pressed, it first deletes it, copies +:regional_indicator_(that letter):, which is the syntax used by Discord for a reaction, to the clipboard, pastes it using ctrl+v, and presses enter. One problem is that the v in ctrl+v overwrites every other letter, so it just spams v, which doesnt do anything, but shoudnt be happening

This is the code:

```py
import pyperclip
from pynput import keyboard
import pyautogui

ctrl_pressed = False

def on_press(key):
    global ctrl_pressed
    pyautogui.press('backspace')
    try:
        if key == keyboard.Key.ctrl:
            ctrl_pressed = True
        if key.char and key.char.isalpha():
            if not (ctrl_pressed and key.char.lower() == 'v'):
                pyperclip.copy("+:regional_indicator_" + key.char.lower() + ":")
                pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
                pyautogui.press('enter')
    except AttributeError:
        if key == keyboard.Key.ctrl:
            ctrl_pressed = True
        elif key in special_keys:
            print(f"Special key pressed: {special_keys[key]}")
        else:
            print(f"Misc key pressed: {key}")

def on_release(key):
    global ctrl_pressed

    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        print("Program closed.")
        return False

    if key == keyboard.Key.ctrl:
        ctrl_pressed = False

special_keys = {
    keyboard.Key.space: "Spațiu",
    keyboard.Key.enter: "Enter",
    keyboard.Key.backspace: "Backspace",
    keyboard.Key.tab: "Tab",
    keyboard.Key.esc: "ESC",
}

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    print("Start.")
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Try this instead `pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v', interval = 0.15)`

Answer (score 0):

When you type `pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')`, there is no interval between pressing control and V. That's why it immediately types V. Each time you want a hotkey in the future, add an interval. For example : `pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v', interval = 0.15)`

Comment: Doesnt seem to work, just made it wayy slower